# Approaches to age estimation with opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision

In the past I've done gender recognition using LDA. Implementation wise it was just like cut and dry facial recognition, I just trained a set of faces and classified them by male or female instead of a name or id. Given a large enough dataset is this approach a viable option?

If the above isn't a good approach (which I don't really think it is), what are some different approaches/methods to perform age estimations with OpenCV?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The work of G.D. Guo and his associates, to my mind, probably represents one of the most recent and focused investigation into this problem of automatic age classification. See [here](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~gdguo/publications.html) for a complete list of publications.

To answer your original question: from the 2010 survey paper "Age Synthesis and Estimation Via Faces: a Survey", a range of data driven techniques are presented as indeed viable from large annotated databases (p. 1968). As for the actual performance of the various algorithms for age estimation: reasonably impressive levels of classification, reported as the Mean Age Error and Cumulative Score metric, are possible (see table 1 on p. 1970) - with the usual caveats as to the choice of feature selection, model representation etc.

How you implement the currently best performing algorithm in OpenCV might prove tricky - but should be possible!

**EDIT**: One quick thing that occurs to me - in  the absence of the currently favoured vogue for Biological Inspired Features, you could use OpenCV's support for the HoG descriptor (which is effectively biologically inspired).

See for example:

[Extracting HoG Features using OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11626140/extracting-hog-features-using-opencv)

[HOG features visualisation with OpenCV, HOGDescriptor in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10862542/hog-features-visualisation-with-opencv-hogdescriptor-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

I've only seen this stuff being done with [Machine Learning](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=seAgiOfu2EIC&pg=PA460&lpg=PA460&dq=opencv%20age&source=bl&ots=hSH96jeFQb&sig=xEXlYiS8rvm_qOQ2FefN6BEWhjI&hl=en&sa=X&ei=CkxqUPe9Ae6y0AGvrYGwDQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=opencv%20age&f=false) through [Cascade Classifier Training](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/user_guide/ug_traincascade.html).